# WebGLRenderingContext.texImage2D does not implement interface ArrayBufferViewOrNull

Tags: opengl-es2, webgl, cubemap

I'm working on a WebGL project and all my textures render fine. 
When i wanted to implement a cubemap i started getting this type error.
`Argument 9 of WebGLRenderingContext.texImage2D does not implement interface ArrayBufferViewOrNull.` in all browsers. 
A fragment of my code i use to load the textures is,

```
    var cubeMap = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, cubeMap);

    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {   
        var img = cubeMapArr[i];
        console.log(img);
        gl.texImage2D(
            gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 
            0, gl.RGB, 1024, 1024, 0, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,img);
    }
```

the `cubeMapArr` holds HTMLImageElements.
Any ideas or experiences about this issue?
Using `gl.texImage2D()` like for example this,

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,normalMapTexture);
```

works with no issues. 
Again `normalMapTexture` holds a HTMLImageElement.

Thank you.

Comment: Searching a lot since 3-4 hours any help will be much appriciated.

Comment: This question is answered in my other post in StackOverflow.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42073596/webglrenderingcontext-teximage2d-does-not-implement-interface-arraybuffervieworn

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was my bad,

First form of the function
`gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,texture);`

accepts these types
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImage2D
but second form accepts only ArrayBufferView or null. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBufferView
 `gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, gl.RGB, 1024, 1024, 0, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,texture);`

So i used the first form with the cubemap, then it worked.

Also `webgl2` context accepts other types in the both forms of these functions, you can check it from the first link again.